# Complete Bootstrap without cdn

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap without cdn as it often requires frequent reconnection to internet to be up to date and this frustrates me when I'm out of connection.

I have downloaded the files from **getbootstrap.com** but then, when I link them, my Dropdown and carousel don't work fine. Also, the files do not contain the fonts folder.

Please can anyone help me with the complete files or a link to get them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you do not have included the bootstrap javascript files. Try it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When using Bootstrap 4, you may also have to include popper before:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/popper.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks DonFattie. I actually included the js files..but didn't know of the popper. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to download and add jQuery & popper. You can alternatively use the CDN for jQuery & popper:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

These need to be included before bootstrap.js:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Using the CDN has advantages for your website users. Since many web pages they visit will use the CDNs, it is likely that they will already be cached by their browsers & will speed up loading your website.

Comment: Thanks alot. I actually wanted to use the offline files while creating the site (that's from my local server) and then change them to their respective CDNs before hosting them Thanks anyway

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped. This will help others with the same problem.